# Failing integration test for Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, integration-testing, powermock

I've been trying to track down an issue with some unit/integration tests I've been writing for an Apache Spark project.

When using Spark 1.1.1 my test passed. When I tried to upgrade to 1.4.0 (also tried 1.4.1) the test starts failing.

I've managed to reduce the code needed to reproduce the issue down to the small integration test below.

Interestingly, if I comment out the @RunWith annotation on the test then the test passes correctly.  Obviously I don't need the @RunWith annotation for this cut down test, but the real tests make use of mocks fairly extensively, so I'd rather not have to drop using PowerMock.

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        SparkConf conf = new     SparkConf(false).setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("My app");
        JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
    }

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I'm seeing

```
java.io.IOException: failure to login
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:842)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:133)
    at com.example.SampleTest.setup(SampleTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Can't find user name
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginModule.commit(UserGroupInformation.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:721)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:719)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:718)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:771)
    ... 38 more
```

The versions of the various dependencies are shown below

- hadoop-client 2.6
- apache spark 1.4.0 / 1.4.1
- junit 4.12
- easy mock 3.31
- power mock 1.6.2

I've tried this with various versions of Spark. The above test passes with the following versions of Spark

- 1.1.1
- 1.2.2

It starts failing from Spark 1.3.0 onwards.

Any ideas what I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the source code for SparkContext, the line causing your exception while trying to get the current user name. In [version 1.2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L321) there was a fallback default `SparkContext.SPARK_UNKNOWN_USER` and it did not required currectly logged in user:

```
 // Set SPARK_USER for user who is running SparkContext.
 val sparkUser = Option {
     Option(System.getenv("SPARK_USER")).getOrElse(System.getProperty("user.name"))
  }.getOrElse {
      SparkContext.SPARK_UNKNOWN_USER
  }
```

This code introduced in [version 1.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L301) does not have default user anymore hence why you don't get this error with earlier versions:

```
// Set SPARK_USER for user who is running SparkContext.
val sparkUser = Utils.getCurrentUserName()
```

This calls the [following code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L2203) in `Utils`:

```
/**
   * Returns the current user name. This is the currently logged in user, unless that's been
   * overridden by the `SPARK_USER` environment variable.
   */
  def getCurrentUserName(): String = {
    Option(System.getenv("SPARK_USER"))
      .getOrElse(UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName())
  }
```

If you set the environment variable `SPARK_USER`, you should be able to prevent the branching to UserGroupInformation which leads to your exception.

`UserGroupInformation` is a Hadoop Security class, and it looks like the use of `PowerMock` is preventing it from working properly.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it fixes the problem. However, setting environment variables in a unit test is a pain. The answer also got me thinking about the problem in a different way and I came up with an alternative solution.  Annotating the class with  @PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.*", "akka.*"}) also fixes the issue (but I haven't yet taken the time to see if this causes other problems)