# InvocationTargetException from within org.apache.hadoop.security packages while exposing Apache Spark Java Code as REST service

Tags: rest, apache-spark

I am trying to expose a Spark ML code written in Java as a REST service on Weblogic. But, while trying to initialize the Spark Context, the code throws **InvocationTargetException** from within the **org.apache.hadoop.security** packages.

Following are the steps I have used:

1. Trained a Spark CrossValidator Naive Bayes model and persisted it in parquet file format. (one time activity)
2. In a Java Web Project, my java source file has a method that loads up the model and uses it to predict the class label for a raw text input [This works standalone, when called from the main() method]
3. A second Java class is exposed as a REST service, and deployed to **Weblogic** along with the **JAX-RS Jersey 2.x** library (that ships with JDeveloper 12.2.1.1) plus all the **jars from the spark 2.0 distribution**.
4. While invoking the REST service, it errors out because of the following error.

Upon analyzing, I found that the code is failing while trying to initialize the SparkContext, which is done in the following way in my Java code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IssuePredictor").setMaster("local").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "spark-warehouse");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
```

I have already tried various ways to refer to the spark-warehouse, including absolute path of the folder or using a relative path like the one specified here. But nothing worked.

**Error Trace:**

> Root cause of ServletException. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.**InvocationTargetException**
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
>       at **org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.**(Groups.java:79)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:74)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:790)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at **org.apache.spark.SparkContext.**(SparkContext.scala:297)
>       at myapps.ml.spark.IssuePredictor.predict(IssuePredictor.java:78)
>
> ...
>
> Caused By: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:132)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:79)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:74)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:790)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2245)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:297)
>       at myapps.ml.spark.IssuePredictor.predict(IssuePredictor.java:78)
>
> ...
>
> Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:659)
>       at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
>       at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
>       at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
>
> ...

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is [this](http://slf4j.org/legacy.html#julRecursion). I.e. You have both jul-to-slf4j.jar and slf4j-jdk14.jar present in your class path.

Looking at your stack traces, Spark is trying to figure out the user and its group mapping when creating your spark context. For this it will need to instantiate (the `ReflectionUtils.newInstance` call in the stack) `ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping` class. In `ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping` there's this static call

```
private static final Log LOG =
    LogFactory.getLog(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.class);
```

because of which you're getting into the above mentioned infinite recursion and end up in stack overflow error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We don't have slf4j-jdk jar in our classpath.
We have removed all slf4j*.jar from our classpath and tested it, but we still get same error.

Comment: Can you try using this SparkConf 

`SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IssuePredictor").setMaster("local").set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "spark-warehouse").set("SPARK_USER", "<give user you want to run job as>");`

This will allow you to bypass the above flow. (But will obviously not solve the logger issue, so you might end up getting that issue somewhere else but at least we can be sure that our understanding is correct if we see same stackoverflow some place else.)

Comment: Followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534458/failing-integration-test-for-apache-spark-streaming

But even after setting the env variable SPARK_USER, we are getting the following error while initializing the SparkContext.

`java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:278)
...
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:659)`

Comment: So that means it is the problem with logger only right. Because now your code is not breaking inside Spark but same StackOverflow exception is coming when you initialize logger inside your `ResponseWriter`. 

Also, `JDK14LoggerAdapter.jav‌​a` is a class inside slf4j-jdk14-xxx.jar

So you need to take care of that dependency. I haven't tried this but you can try removing jul-to-slf4j.jar from Spark jars and see what results.